# Easy Bit-Level Serialiation

Tags: c++, boost, binary-serialization

I'm looking for a C++ API to *conveniently* an *efficiently* serialize/unserialize (user-defined) types of arbitrary bit-size into some structure (preferrably template class) containing a set of bits. I believe `boost::dynamic_bitset` is good start but it doesn't contain functions/operators for appending builtin-types such `uint8_t`, `uint16_t` etc.

I want this to work something like in the following example

```
boost::dynamic_bitset bs;
bs.append((uint8_t)123);
bs.append((uint16_t)12345, big_endian);
```

Stream operators should be supported aswell with a state-dependent endian-behaviour:

```
bs << (uint8_t)(123);
bs << little_endian;
bs << (uint16_t)(12345); // serialized as little_endian
bs << big_endian;
```

I also know of Boost.Serialization and Boost.Endian (in Boost Sandbox). I would like something like that extended to the bit-level.

I believe `boost::dynamic_bitset`'s member functions

```
void append(Block block);
```

and

```
template <typename BlockInputIterator>
void append(BlockInputIterator first, BlockInputIterator last);
```

are too low level for most users. I guess it should be reused in these new `append` functions. To optimize even more expression templates could be used to group consecutive serializations into larger (byte-sized) blocks before appending them to the `dynamic_bitset`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any library, but it isn't that hard to write a BitBufferReader/Writer yourself and it will be completely to your requirements.

Comment: Is `BitBufferReader/Writer` some class you instantiate `boost::dynamic_bitset` with?

Comment: I would use an ordinary container (vector/array) with a byte-offset and a bit-offset, but you can use what you find most appropriate.